# Multiple models in one view ASP.Net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to ASP.Net MVC. I have three models `Employee`, `Address`, `Store`. The structures are as follows...

```
EMPLOYEE:-
    EmpID(PK), EmpName, Rank, StoreID, AddID
STORE:-
    StoreID(pk), BranchName, AddID
ADDRESS:-
    AddId(pk), Address, Phone, ID(fk EMPLOYEE.EmpID, fk STORE.StoreID)
```

How to use all three models in one controller and how to perform CRUD operations in controller. In the view of `Employee`, I want to show all the fields of all three of models, e.g.

```
EmpID, EmpName, Rank, Store.BranchName, Address, Phone
```

When I update these fields in view, all models should be updated. I know if how to use multiple models without relationship between them.
Thanks.

Comment: Write a Class with 3 properties and each property is of type your each model. So this class wraps all 3 models use this wrapper class to play with. And this wrapper class is Called ViewModel in MVC ... Use this viewModel to pass data from controller to view..

Answer (score 4):

This is where a view model comes in handy. It allows you to separate your database layer fields and logic from your presentation layer fields.

You can combine several database entities and only expose the elements of each that you want to display on the front end.

For example, you might define your view model like:

```
public class EmployeeInfo
{
    public string EmployeeName {get;set;}
    // other properties

    public EmployeeInfo(Employee emp, Store store, Address address)
    {
        EmployeeName = emp.EmpName;
        // assign other properties
    }
}
```

Then, in your controller, you can create the view model and pass it to the view:

```
public class EmployeeController
{
     public IActionResult Index()
     {
         var empInfo = new EmployeeInfo(employee, store, address); // retrieved from database somehow
         return View(empInfo);
     }
}
```

Then, your view can reference the view model and use the properties like you would normally.

Comment: `The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Models.EmployeeDetails', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable``1[Models.EmployeeDetails]'.` This error comes. I did `public class EmployeeInfo : IEnumarable`.

Comment: You will probably need to change the types in the constructor to match, I was just demonstrating the concept.

Comment: @DhavalR not really without seeing your full code, I'm sure you can figure the best way to modify this example for your specific use-case. You will probably need to send a collection of the View Model type to the view, with one per employee record.

Answer (score 0):

Employee have relationship with the address & Store,

**Model**

```
 namespace Tester.Models
{
    public class EMPLOYEEVIEWMODEL
    {
        public int EmpID { get; set; }
        public string EmpName { get; set; }
        public int Rank { get; set; }
        public ADDRESSVIEWMODEL Address { get; set; }
        public STOREVIEWMODEL Store { get; set; }

    }

    public class STOREVIEWMODEL
    {
        public int StoreID { get; set; }
        public string BranchName { get; set; }       
    }
    public class ADDRESSVIEWMODEL
    {
        public int AddId { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }        
    }

}
```

**Controller**

```
namespace Tester.Controllers
{
    public class EmployeeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Employee/

        public ActionResult Add()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

**View**

```
@using Tester.Models;
@model EMPLOYEEVIEWMODEL
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Add</title>
</head>
<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmpName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.EmpName, new { @class = "form-control input-sm" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmpName, "", new { @class = "help-block" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Rank, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Rank, new { @class = "form-control input-sm" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Rank, "", new { @class = "help-block" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Store.BranchName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Store.BranchName, new { @class = "form-control input-sm" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Store.BranchName, "", new { @class = "help-block" })
            </div>
        </div>}
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address.Address, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Address.Address, new { @class = "form-control input-sm" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address.Address, "", new { @class = "help-block" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address.Phone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Address.Phone, new { @class = "form-control input-sm" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address.Phone, "", new { @class = "help-block" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <input id="Submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
</body>
</html>
```

Kindly look into this & let me know your feedback

Answer (score 0):

Using Dynamic Model

Models

```
public class Teacher
{
  public int TeacherId { get; set; }
  public string Code { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
} 

public class Student
{
  public int StudentId { get; set; }
  public string Code { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string EnrollmentNo { get; set; }
}


 Controller Code

 public class HomeController : Controller
 {
     public ActionResult Index()
     {
        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to my demo!";
        dynamic mymodel = new ExpandoObject();
        mymodel.Teachers = GetTeachers();
        mymodel.Students = GetStudents();
        return View(mymodel);
     }
 }
```

We can define our model as dynamic (not a strongly typed model) using the @model dynamic keyword.

```
View Code

   @using MultipleModelInOneView;

   @model dynamic

   @{

     ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";

   }

   <h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>



    <p><b>Teacher List</b></p>



   <table>

   <tr>

    <th>Id</th>

    <th>Code</th>

    <th>Name</th>

</tr>

@foreach (Teacher teacher in Model.Teachers)

{

    <tr>

        <td>@teacher.TeacherId</td>

        <td>@teacher.Code</td>

        <td>@teacher.Name</td>

    </tr>

}
```

**Student List**

Id

        Code

        Name

        Enrollment No

    

    @foreach (Student student in Model.Students)

    {

        

            @student.StudentId

            @student.Code

            @student.Name

            @student.EnrollmentNo

          

       }